# Next build fails only on my machine with `Generating static pages (0/6)TypeError: n.replaceAll is not a function`

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, yarnpkg

I am trying to build my Next.js project, but I am getting the error `Generating static pages (0/6)TypeError: n.replaceAll is not a function` at a file in my `node_modules` folder.
Steps I have taken to try to identify where the problem is coming from:

(In the following when I say install&build I mean `yarn install --frozen-lockfile`, then `next build`

1. delete `node_modules` and `.next` folder, insall&build -> fails
2. clone the repo in a new folder and install&build -> fails
3. Run this as a github action on github -> succeeds
4. Run this as a github action on my machine using this library: https://github.com/nektos/act (that uses docker) -> succeeds
5. do step 1 on my colleagues machine -> succeeds
6. do step 2 on my colleagues machine -> succeds

The full error is:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/404". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: n.replaceAll is not a function
    at file:///home/sev/dev/frontend/node_modules/connectkit/build/index.es.js:682:37384
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at rn (file:///home/sev/dev/frontend/node_modules/connectkit/build/index.es.js:682:37367)
    at file:///home/sev/dev/frontend/node_modules/connectkit/build/index.es.js:682:37304
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at tn (file:///home/sev/dev/frontend/node_modules/connectkit/build/index.es.js:682:37270)
    at kn (file:///home/sev/dev/frontend/node_modules/connectkit/build/index.es.js:682:42706)
    at Wc (/home/sev/dev/frontend/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/home/sev/dev/frontend/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/home/sev/dev/frontend/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
```

Comment: What version of Node are you using?

Comment: @SteveHolgado We are using next `next@12.3.1` - when I check for node it's not installed in this repo

Comment: Can you run `node --version` in your terminal?

Comment: @SteveHolgado v14.18.1 - in the github actions I think its only run with v16

Comment: Ok so `replaceAll` is only supported from Node v15.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because `String.prototype.replaceAll()` is only supported from Node v15.0.0:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#browser_compatibility

You will need to update your version of Node to at least this version.

I hope this helps to resolve your issue.